Need help finding offsets to ESP and EBP
I am trying to understand how the offset is calculated from ebp to esp in 32-bit.
My understanding is that when you push to the stack, esp is decremented and points to a lower address, 4 bytes at a time on 32-bit. I assumed that (ebp - 4) was right to get to a1fa1fa since that is decrementing--but then I did (esp + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4) to get offset from esp, which was incorrect.
How is it 28?


It's not 28 in that diagram.
a1fa1fa is one stack slot (dword) below EBP, four above ESP.
It can be addressed as [ebp-4] or [esp+16].
And I see that's what you put in; talk to your instructor about the error in their quiz program.
